# Nav2 Local and Global Plugins

Tags: ros2, nav2

Is there a way to change runtime plugins like below for local and global costmap from BT in order to disable `obstacle_layer` as needed  ?

```
plugins: ["plugin1", "plugin2"]
plugin1: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
plugin2: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer", "obstacle_layer"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the layers have an `enabled` parameter that you can dynamically set on/off as you like.